# How to create an alert dialog with single choice list item which depends of a text file in an Android app

Tags: android, text, android-alertdialog

In my app, I'm actually able to change the current CPU governor, max and min frequency of the processor but now I want to be able to create custom profile. For that, I have to display the available frequencies and governor offered by the kernel (the informations are given in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies and scaling_available_governor).

But I'm stuck with the alert dialog. I really don't know how to create one that display the entire text file one frequency per one frequency in one line which can be selected and written into the appropriate file that change the min, max frequency or the governor!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, But to display AlertDialog as multiple choice use this:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

    String[]  groups = mGroupNames;
    boolean[] selected = mGroupIsSelected;

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
    .setTitle("title")
    .setMultiChoiceItems(mGroupNames, mGroupIsSelected,new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
            mGroups.get(which).setSelected(isChecked);
        }
    })
    .setPositiveButton( android.R.string.ok,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        }
    })
    .create();

}
```

your class has to extend

```
extends DialogFragment
```

Comment: In fact I've a text file with multiple words (for example all the cpu governor available). What I want is to display all the words contents in the text file: 1 word on one line. For example: I have 10 word so 10 lines. The issue is that if a user change his kernel, the number of CPU governor can be changed so the alert dialog should "adapt" to the content of the text file. Sorry if I expressed myself badly ^^

Comment: You can use ListFragment http://androide-examples.blogspot.com/2013/11/android-scroll-list.html here is the example...

Answer (score 0):

insted

```
.setMultiChoiceItems(mGroupNames, mGroupIsSelected,new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
        mGroups.get(which).setSelected(isChecked);
    }
})
```

use

```
.setItems(mGroupNames, null)
```

where mGroupNames are Strings you want to show to the user

Comment: Nice, I suppose that I have to associate the text file to mGroupNames. But after that, how can I do for associate one word that is in the file to a choice ?

Comment: In implementation onClick(...) define your saving.

Comment: Yes, I've created a stringTokenizer for detect each words in the file. I've stocked each tokens in an array that is displayed in the alert dialog !

Comment: If my comments helped you. please do make a note.